# AUTOSAR Configuration - NVM

Tags: nvm, autosar

I try to write into the memory using `NvM_Write();` there is a positive response from the **UDS**.

When I try to read the same block, there is no response and the software goes into det with `NvM_PENDING state`. I reset and then try to read the same memory block, there is no data in that block (it is just 0x00).

NvM_Write leads to `Fee_Write` but `Fls_Write` is never called. Is this a configuration issue?

Debugged and found that `Fls_Write` is never called. The Nvm, Fee and fls are called once every 5 ms. When I request NvM_Write, the request is put in a queue to be serviced in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem in your setup. I wonder, if you have a task, that calls `NvM_Mainfunction()`, `Fee_Mainfunction()` and `Fls_Mainfunction()`. NvM handles requests like `NvM_ReadBlock()` and `NvM_WriteBlock()` by a Queue, which is worked on by the mainfunctions on task level.

Regarding UDS Service, the request returned a positive response most likely due to the fact, that you used the return value of the `NvM_WriteBlock()`, which will be `E_OK` if the *request* to write was accepted by NvM and put in the NvM Queue. If the request was not accepted it returns `E_NOT_OK`.

The diagnostic service implementation should actually wait for the NvM_GetErrorStatus(BlockID) return value changing from `NVM_REQ_PENDING` to return `NVM_REQ_OK`  or something else like `NVM_REQ_NOT_OK`.

I guess, that your implementation was implemented by hand, because with a proper configuration, the Dcm has a standard behaviour described in requirement SWS_Dcm_00541, just as I have explained above.

Comment: Implementation was not by hand. I know that the UDS sends a positive response since it has accepted the request, and it is not a guarantee that the nvm has written data. There seems to be a problem with the configuration of nvm/fee/fls. I am just struggling to find out which one.

Comment: When you say, it is generated, do you mean the Dcm WRDBI service has DcmDspDidUse-
Port is set to USE_ATOMIC_NV_DATA_INTERFACE? Because this should handle the write including the status polling. Then it might be a problem of e.g. a Task handling of the mainfunctions and/or maybe a task priority problem.